# How to use fromEvent in angular with mat-datepicker

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-material

I need to get events from material datepicker and call method stopPropagation. How can I achieve this using fromEvent ?

This is example of code I have tried. Im using document, but i need to change fromEventSource to the datepicker

```
fromEvent<KeyboardEvent>(document, 'keydown').pipe(
            filter((event) => event.key === 'Escape'),
        ).subscribe(e => e.stopPropagation());
```

And where i can use it? Currently I'm using it in ngOnInit and i can see events of document if i add console.log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly and you want to listen to this event globally in the DOM, I think the best way to do this would be to use [HostListener](https://angular.io/api/core/HostListener) instead

"Angular invokes the supplied handler method when the host element emits the specified event, and updates the bound element with the result."

Here is my suggestion to stop propagation of Esc:

```
@HostListener('document:keydown', ['$event'])
  handleKeyboardEvent(event: any) {
    if (event?.keyCode === 27) {  //ESCAPE KEY
      event.stopPropagation()
    }
  }
```